# Por que a função vogal não retorna o valor certo?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Estou tentando fazer uma função que lê um arquivo em txt e retorna a quantidade de vogais no arquivo.

```
const fs = require('fs');
let texto = "Teste";//tem 2 vogais
fs.writeFile("teste.txt",texto ,(err)=>{
    if(err) {
        throw err;
    }

    console.log("Arquivo salvo");
});

function vogal (file) {
    const letras = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"];
    var cont = 1;    
    fs.readFile(file, (err, data) =>{
        if(err) throw err;

        data.toString().split("").forEach(itemTexto =>{
            letras.forEach(itemLetra=>{
                if(itemTexto === itemLetra) cont++;
            });
        });

    });
    return cont;//retorna 1
}

console.log(vogal("teste.txt"));
```

Comment: Retornar tamanho de consoante somente?

Comment: Você está contando as vogais, só dará o valor certo se tiver uma coincidência muito grande no texto. Saiba mais neste link: https://escolakids.uol.com.br/portugues/consoantes.htm (comentado pelo Maury)

Comment: @Bacco copiando meu comentário? Eu não ofendi autor da mensagem. Coloquei aquilo porque fiquei confuso.

Comment: @MauryDeveloper como foi removido, eu não quis perder seu link relevante e repostei.

Comment: Nenhum problema. Quem removeu....

Comment: Peço perdão pelo erro, acabei me confundindo com os nomes, mas o objetivo é contar as vogais. Vou editar a pergunta para ficar mais claro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você está retornando o valor de `cont` antes de terminar de ler o seu arquivo. Como já deve saber, as operações de entrada e saída do JavaScript são assíncronas, isso significa que o callback no qual você conta os caracteres no seu arquivo é a ultima coisa a rodar na sua função.

Se quiser retornar o valor de um processo assíncrono, terá que retornar dentro de uma Promise, ou então, faça o `console.log` dentro da própria função:

```
const fs = require('fs')
const util = require('util')

async function consoante(file) {
    // Não me responsabilizo por letras como H, W e Y
    var consoantes = new Set('bBcCdDfFgGjJkKlLmMnNpPqQrRsStTvVwWxXzZ')
    var cont = 0

    var readFile = util.promisify(fs.readFile)
    var buffer = await readFile(file)

    var str = buffer.toString().normalize('NFD')
    for (var c of str)
        if (consoantes.has(c)) cont++

    console.log(`Número de consoantes: ${cont}`)
}
```

Comment: "JavaScript é assíncrono"?

Comment: As operações de `io` são

Comment: Sim, mas o JS não é :D

Comment: A edição ficou melhor +1

Comment: Só comentando: O nodejs adicionou a função [`fs.readFileSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options) na **v0.1.8**, mas achei interessante o `promisify`. +1 =D